# Error in codeigniter Call to undefined method CI_Loader

Tags: php

I am new user of codeigniter i coded in modle and when i load the model in controller it gave me earror

the error is: 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::modle() in C:\wamp\www\CI\application\controllers\Test.php on line 10**

My model code is:

```
<?
class Sitemodle extends CI_Model
{

    function getall()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query=$this->db->get('2');
        if ($query-> num_rows()>0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row ) 
            {
                $data[]=$row;
            }
        return $data;  
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and controller code is this:

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller{


 function index()
    {
    $this->load->modle('Sitemodle');

    $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `modle` method. Try `model`.

Comment: thanks phantom the problem is solved.

Comment: can you suggest me a links about codeignitor phantom

Comment: Please consider revisiting your question as per the current situation it stands for a very low quality post and will attract many down-votes as well....

Comment: @user3095653 here you go, https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->load->model('Sitemodle');
```

It is spelled wrong it should be model to load the model of CI

And for user guide  you can use the URL of your project/user_guide its there only with the CI project folder. Just you need to access it.